# Animate a car using jquery and css using live acceleration data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I have a basic car model that is animated using CSS.

On the other hand, I have a live data stream consists of acceleration on the x and z-axis The data are retrieved from a remote server using server-sent-event (sse). I want to be able to use the acceleration data to animate the car accordingly. The goal is to move the car forward up/down using accelerationZ and right/left using accelerationX.

This is how the car look like in 2D:

[image: truckSimDemo]

I am just not sure how to include continuously changing live data in css and make the animation changes according to the input data so the car can accelerate and decelerate.

[This is the current code](https://github.com/samiarja/vehicle-sim-demo) of the car simulation model based on html/css/JS. Currently I am using constant value for track velocity and wheel rotation speed like shown below:

```
.track{
    height:60vh;
    width:800vw;
    background-image: url(./img/track.png);
    position:absolute;
    top:70vh;
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    animation: carMove linear 13s infinite;
}
.car{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-image: url(./img/miningtruck.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    bottom:15vh;
    animation: shake linear .5s infinite;
}
.wheel1 img{
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top:215px;
    left:42px;
    animation: wheelRotation linear .5s infinite;
}

.wheel2 img{
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top: -0px;
    left: 275px;
    animation: wheelRotation linear .5s infinite;
```

My concern is how to replace the 13s or .5s by a dynamically changing value accX and accZ

This is how I get the live feed using sse to get accx and accz:

```
    // globally initial the sensorAddr, accX and accZ to be able to use in other function
    // these values comes from the onMsg function 
    let sensorAddr = 0;
    let accX = 0;
    let accZ = 0;


    // how to include the jquery code here to send 
    // the acceleration to the css to dynamically animate
    // the vehicle


    StartRetrieveLiveData();

    function onMsg(event) {
    
            var received_msg = event.data;
            var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(received_msg));
    
            if (obj !== null) {
    
                if (
                    obj.hasOwnProperty("DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue") &&
                    obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["DataMapAddress"] !==
                    undefined
                ) {
                    sensorAddr =
                        obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["DataMapAddress"];
    
                    if (sensorAddr == 1) {
                        accX =
                            obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["Value"];
                            console.log("AccX", accX);
                    }
                    if (sensorAddr == 3) {
                        accZ =
                            obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["Value"];
                            console.log("AccZ", accZ);
                    }
                    if (sensorAddr == 204) {
                        timeStamp =
                            obj["DataMapChangedObjectsAddressValue"][0]["Value"];
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }
    
        function onOpen(e) {
            console.log("SSE connected");
        }
    
        function onError(e) {
            // console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);
            if (e.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) this.source.close();
            if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
                console.log("SSE Disconnected");
            } else if (e.target.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING) {
                console.log("SSE Connecting ...");
            }
        }
    
        function StartRetrieveLiveData() {
            if (!!window.EventSource) {
                this.source = new EventSource("/sse");
            } else {
                console.log("Your browser doesn't support SSE");
            }
    
            this.source.addEventListener("message", e => this.onMsg(e));
    
            this.source.addEventListener("open", e => this.onOpen(e), false);
    
            this.source.addEventListener("error", e => this.onError(e), false);
    
        }
```

I would appreciate any feedback. Any hint or a better approach would be great. I just want a head starter making any significant to the code.

Comment: You could override the css-attribute like `$('.track').css ('animation', 'carMove linear 15s infinite')`.

Comment: how to include the continuous value from the accelerometer (e.g. accX and accZ)? and why do we have to keep "carMove linear 15s infinite"

Comment: No i meant that you could use that JQuery function in your `onMsg` method. There you calculate the `animation` and update it accordingly.

Comment: While I understood what you mean, but I am not sure how to implement this. it would be great if there is an example that you could refer to?